# Radius of Convergence for $ \lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)} = |x+1|^2 < \frac{1}{3} $

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find radius of convergence for a function $ f $ such that:

\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty}{f(x)} = |x+1|^2 < \frac{1}{3} \end{align}

Now it seems that the limit can have two solutions:

\begin{align}
|x+1| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \text{ or } |x+1| > \frac{1}{-\sqrt{3}}  \end{align}

I am confused over which to reject or whether I should even reject any of them. Could someone please advise me on what to do?

Comment: Where in this question are we supposed to see a radius of convergence? Please explain.

Comment: @Did I am supposed to determine the radius of convergence for function f using rario test. But I got the above limit. Hence, I was unsure which one to use as the solution for the limit. But since one inequality can be rejected, I can now determine that the radius of convergence is $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $ as mentioned below.

Comment: Radiuses of convergence are for power series. Where is there a power series here?

Comment: @Did I calculated the limit using the ratio of the power series that I was trying to evaluate. In my question, I am only concerned about finding the value of the limit which is required to determine the radius of convergence of the power series that I am working on.

Comment: Then it is odd that the answer below satisfies you since it assumes that $x$ is real while the radius of convergence of a power series refers to $x$ complex. Whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that always $|x|\ge 0$. So simply ignore the second inequality and work with:
$$|x+1|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
which implies:
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<x+1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$